# Why the ComplexExpand is not working here?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

The ComplexExpand seems not to be working in the following where all variable are real:

```
   rigidity[x_, y_, z_, a_, q_, b_, c_, d_, \[Phi]_] = 
   {{2*x*a*d, 0, 2*x*a*c, 0, -2*y*a*d, 0, 
     -2*z*b*c - (z*q*d)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*d, 
     (I*z*q*d)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - I*E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*d, 
     (-E^((-I)*\[Phi]))*z*q*c - E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*c + 2*z*b*d}, 
    {0, -2*x*a*d, 0, -2*y*a*d, 0, -2*y*a*c, 
     (I*z*q*d)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - I*E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*d, 
     -2*z*b*c + (z*q*d)/E^(I*\[Phi]) + E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*d, 
     (I*z*q*c)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - I*E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*c}, 
    {2*x*a*b, 0, (x*a*q)/E^(I*\[Phi]) + E^(I*\[Phi])*x*a*q, 0, 
     -2*y*a*b, (I*y*a*q)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - I*E^(I*\[Phi])*y*a*q, 
     (-E^((-I)*\[Phi]))*z*q*b - E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*b + 2*z*c*d, 
     (I*z*q*b)/E^(I*\[Phi]) - I*E^(I*\[Phi])*z*q*b, 
     z*a^2 - z*q^2 + z*b^2 + z*c^2 - z*d^2}}; 
R1[x_, y_, z_, a_, q_, b_, c_, d_, \[Phi]_] := 
  SingularValueList[rigidity[x, y, z, a, q, b, c, d, \[Phi]]][[1]][[
   1]]
R1[x, y, z, a, q, b, c, d, \[Phi]]
ComplexExpand[%]
```

The result contains terms like `Conjugate[x a b]` etc, when it is expected to treat all variables as real. What is wrong here?

Comment: While the variables are all real, the expression is complex and it must contain functions to address that. You can use the option `TargetFunctions` to control how that is done, e.g., `ComplexExpand[R1[x, y, z, a, q, b, c, d, \[Phi]], 
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`

Comment: The expression is actually a singular value, which cannot be complex! I think there must be a way of simplifying it further.

Comment: @Bob’s suggestion got rid of the conjugates in the `Root[]` objects — isn’t that what you wanted?

Comment: `SingularValueList[rigidity[x, y, z, a, q, b, c, d, \[Phi]]][[1]]` is a singular value. `SingularValueList[rigidity[x, y, z, a, q, b, c, d, \[Phi]]][[1]][[1]]` is a subexpression of a singular value and in general can be complex.